# How to offer scalars as coordinates of the data points for pyplot's plot function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am reading document of the pyplot's plot function here: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot. It said the Parameters x, y: array-like or scalar.

I understand how to using array-like data, but not scalar. Can anyone give some examples to show how to use scalar x, y parameter? Thanks.

Comment: For numpy, scalar is a single int or float.

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(y)
```

as plot(100) or some other number. It will plot a single point.

Comment: yeah, I thought about that, but one thing which confuse me was that I didn't see anything, like this:plt.plot(1, 2, "x")
plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking too much about the the definition of scalar number. For this purpose, it just means a int or float. Use the following code to plot.

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Also make sure that you have imported `matplotlib` correctly. The best method is

```
import matplotlib as plt
```